# How Validation.HasError property is updated for user input validation?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

In [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/784331/WPF-MVVM-Validation-ViewModel-using-IDataErrorInfo) there is a text box that shows a pink background for invalid data. This is the wpf code:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Aid,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" 
             Canvas.Left="95" Canvas.Top="60" Width="297">

<TextBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger  Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Pink"/>
                        ...
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBox.Style>

        <Validation.ErrorTemplate>
            <ControlTemplate>                    
                <StackPanel>
                    <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="textBox" ToolTip="{Binding [0].ErrorContent}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Validation.ErrorTemplate>

    </TextBox>
```

But I don't get how Validation.HasError is updated as the user inputs the value?

Comment: There are several ways. The one I like most is to implement [INotifyErrorInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) in the view model. You'll find a lot of Information about INotifyErrorInfo in the net and here in Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sample project takes advantage of IDataErrorInfo interface which makes data validation very simple. [This link will describe it in details](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/858492/WPF-Validation-Using-IDataErrorInfo).